# VSCode - @ absolute path autocomplete does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have a VueJS Application and when I use `@` absolute path on `import` the autocomplete does not work.

```
//autocomplete does not work in any place like this
import useVehicle from '@/composables/vehicle'
useVehicle.

//autocomplete works in both lines like this
import useVehicle from '../../composables/vehicle'
useVehicle. //shows autocomplete
```

The `@/` is the `src/` path, is there any way to make it work well in VSCode?